# How bad is this method for requesting images instead of AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, src

I have a thumbnail image list, all of them have an attribute of 'rel' which is the source of the same image in bigger size. My function is simple, if you click on a thumbnail image, the bigger size of it loads in a container. The interesting part of my code, which I need your feedback about, is this :

The variables:

'event.data.cImg' is the bigger image in the container which I want to update
'event.data.cImgWrap' is the container for the bigger image
'$(this)' is the thumbnail image which was clicked

```
event.data.cImg.attr('src', $(this).attr("rel"));

  if (event.data.cImg.complete != 'true') {

      event.data.cImgWrap.css('opacity', '0.7');

      event.data.cImg.load(function() {
          event.data.cImgWrap.css('opacity', '1');
      });
  }
```

So what are the disadvantages of my code?

Sorry for my English, I'm not a native speaker and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant think of one reason where you want to use ajax to load an image , unless the images are stored directly in the database as base64 encoded datas ( and not every browser support data urls ). the DOM has already everything you need to "monitor" image loading , so what the point using ajax to get an image ? a simple GET http request does  the trick.

The only thing you would use ajax for is fetching the image url and metadatas like title ,etc from a list of images through a webservice ...
as suggested before , the complete event is not supported everywhere.

Comment: And is using GET better in any ways than my function?

Comment: I see, I thought you were talking about jQuery.get().

Comment: $.get desugars (uses) in $.ajax in jquery ,internally.

Answer (score 2):

Not all browsers support the `complete` property of images.

I would suggest setting the `load` handler and the `opacity` before changing the `src`. Then, change the `src`. If the image is already in cache, the `load` event will fire immediately, setting the opacity back to `1`. All being well, the user will not get to see the opacity change, because it happens faster than the screen refreshes.